# Compose key stops working?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compose-key

Running 16.04, single-user system. I set up the right-alt key to be the compose key. It worked fine.

Next day when I rebooted my computer, the compose key was disabled so I went into Keyboard settings and reset it back to right-alt. It worked fine.

This morning I fired up my computer, tried to use right-alt as compose and the key doesn't work. Checked keyboard settings and the compose key is set to right-alt, rather than disabled.

I reset the compose key to right-control, that works. When I switched the compose key back to right-alt, it remained an alt key.

What's going on, and how can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I do have this problem since upgrading to 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla), no problems before in 20.04. Right now, my kludgy workaround is to start `gnome-tweaks` ("Tweaks") and in "Keyboard & Mouse" temporarily setting the Compose Key to something else and then restoring it to Right-Alt.

This is obviously not a lasting solution, but the best I have to offer.

Comment: It seems to be related to unplugging/replugging the laptop to an external monitor/keyboard, but haven't figured out the details yet.

Comment: A possibly related bug is that characters entered using the Compose key in Telegram Desktop start appearing more than once.